# determine whether a list is sublist of another list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have just write a predicate to determine whether a list is sublist of another list.

```
sublist( [], _ ).
sublist( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
sublist( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X|XS], XSS ).
```

But this predicate can only deal with situation like this.

```
1 ?- sublist([1,2,3], [0,1,0,2,0,3,0]).
true .
```

Can it also deal with list that its sequence is different from another list?

```
2 ?- sublist([['D','A','G'],['V','E','D']], [['V','E','D'],['D','A','G']]).
false.
```

Any help will be appreciated~~

Answer (score 3):

I guess from your question that you are looking for subset and not sublist.
If each an item from the first list can have multiplicity and you want it to be succeed you can write:

```
subset([], _).
subset([X|Tail], Y):-
  memberchk(X, Y),
  subset(Tail, Y).
```

First clause is the base case, and second clause checks whether the item is in Y, and proceeds recursion with the tail from the first list and the second list as-is.

If each item in the first list "consumes" an item from the second list, then you would write:

```
subset([], _).
subset([X|Tail], Y):-
  select(X, Y, Z),
  subset(Tail, Z).
```

In this case, the second clause uses `select/3` so that the matching element is removed from the second list upon recursion.